# how can I find the position of the last LETTER in a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, find

I want to include a function in my code that can return the position in the string that the last letter in the string can be found.

e.g: if the input were " hello world k ...^&", the function could return 14, (since that would be the position of the character k)

Comment: How do you define "letter"?

Comment: @CodingPigeon the index for letter k is 13 since Python counts from 0, not 14

Answer (score 1):

This finds the last letter, and uses the length of what comes before it to get the number you want:

```
def last_letter_pos(s):
    return len(re.match('^(.*)[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*$',s).groups()[0])+1
```

Comment: Why the `^` and the `[^a-zA-Z]*$`? Neither seems necessary.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "include", but the `[a-zA-Z]` bit matches you "last letter" and the part after it makes sure there isn't another after it.

Comment: thanks, it works great! would you know how the code could be modified to find the position of the first letter in a string?

Comment: using regex for this problem is similar to using a nuke for tearing down a house; it works, but it's massive overkill and funny enough less performant than a simple loop.

Comment: @CodingPigeon check the answer I posted for finding the position of the first/last index

Answer (score 1):

since you didn't define what a letter is, I just used ascii_letters, but you can choose whatever set of characters you want (by passing letters to the function). It then scans the string from the end until it finds a letter and returns its index. If no letter was found, it returns `None`:

```
from string import ascii_letters

def find_index(string ,letters=set(ascii_letters), from_end=True):
    iterator = range(len(string)-1,-1,-1) if from_end else range(len(string))
    for i in iterator:
        if string[i] in letters:
            return i

s = ' hello world k ...^&'
i = find_index(s)
print(f"Last index: {i}\t Character: {s[i]}")
i = find_index(s, find_last=False)
print(f"First index: {i}\t Character: {s[i]}")
```

Edit: this should be faster than the proposed regex method as it doesn't try to match the string from the start to the end, while being less verbose for choosing a set of letters.

Edit 2: since you want a configurable direction (last/first) I updated the solution to allow this change by choosing a different `range` depending on the `from_end` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use enumerate() and isalpha() to obtain positions of letters and max() to find the last one:

```
S = " hello world k ...^&"      

p = max(p for p,c in enumerate("x"+S) if c.isalpha())

print(p) #14
```

*Note that this will return a one-based position (not an index) and the result will be zero if the string has no letters at all.*

Answer (score -1):

If you mean not punctuation chars

```
s = " hello world k ...^&"
len(list(filter(lambda c: c not in string.punctuation, s)))-1
14
```

or for letters only

```
len(list(filter(lambda c: c in string.ascii_letters, s)))-1
```

Comment: What if there is punctuation before the last letter?

Answer (score -1):

You could iterate the string in reverse and count the characters until you find the first letter:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def last_letter_pos(s):
    return len(s) - sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x: not x.isalpha(),
                                             reversed(s))) - 1

last_letter_pos(" hello world k ...^&")
# 13

last_letter_pos('12.3')
# -1
```

Variant with a custom generator:

```
def nonletters(s):
    for letter in reversed(s):
        if letter.isalpha():
            return
        yield True
        
def last_letter_pos(s):
    return len(s) - sum(nonletters(s)) -1
```

Here the output is `13` since python counts from 1, and you get -1 if there is no letter (you can use a conditional to return something else in that case).

Comment: Are you sure that python counts from 1?  I thought it counted from zero.

Comment: @EllieKesselman this is a typo, python indeed counts from zero ;)